# Replacing an SVG with an image

Tags: javascript, events, svg

I want to replace this SVG object with an image in the exact same position.
There's probably a CSS way to go about it, but for a specific reason I'd much rather have this worked out entirely using Javascript!

```
<circle id="Sun" class="st0" cx="500" cy="300.8" r="30.3" onclick="changePic();"/>
```

This is the function that's probably in need of some tweaking.

```
function changePic(src)
{
        var im = document.getElementById("Sun"); 
        im.setAttribute("Sun",  "im");
        im.setAttribute("src", src || "img/picture.png");       
}
```

`"img/picture.png"` is the folder and the image inside.

Also, is there a way in Javascript to call this function when the SVG is double clicked, as opposed to one click. I know it's not what I asked but I'd be grateful if I were helped out with that one too.

Comment: Wouldn't it work to just delete the svg element from the parent node, and then have it add a new <img> tag with the proper src?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```js
var svg = document.getElementById('Sun');

var src; // undefined

if (svg) {
  svg.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.setAttribute("Sun", "im");
    img.src = src || "img/picture.png";

    this.parentNode.replaceChild(img, this);
  }, false);
}
```

```html
<!-- <circle id="Sun" class="st0" cx="500" cy="300.8" r="30.3" onclick="changePic();" /> -->

<svg id="Sun" class="st0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="25" fill="#191919" />
</svg>
```